# Unable passing data from one intent to another intent

Tags: android-intent

I have tried to pass some data from one intent to another. But while running this code on android studio when I press the button after putting the value on my first intent it shows that "intent has stopped.

** I wanted to pass data from activity-1 to activity-2

activity-1:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


EditText edit1;
EditText edit2;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edit1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    edit2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

                i.putExtra("username", edit1.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("password", edit2.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

}

---

activity -2

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView txt1;
TextView txt2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit3);
    txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit4);

    Intent i2=this.getIntent();
String message=i2.getStringExtra("username");

    String message2=i2.getStringExtra("password");

    txt1.setText(message);
    txt2.setText(message2);



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You try this code.

activity-1:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        EditText edit1, edit2;
        Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            edit1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);             
            edit2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
            btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

                        String val1 = edit1.getText().toString();
                        String val2 = edit2.getText().toString();
                        intent.putExtra("username", val1);
                        intent.putExtra("password", val2);
                        startActivity(intent);          
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

activity-2:

```
    public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit3);
            txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit4);

            String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
            String password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");

            txt1.setText(message);
            txt2.setText(password);         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, bro. But now it shows "intent keeps stopping" after running. I can't even put the value in first intent.